# How to insert data dynamically in different tables?

Tags: sql-server

I created dynamic survey. i want to copy the same survey to another survey id.

SurveyTable:

```
SID SName Created Date
```

QuestionTable

```
QID Question SID
```

AnswerOptionsTable

```
AID Answer QID
```

Now i created one survey for that i added questions and answers. But i want to copy the 
same survey with another SName so that remaining table also changed accordingly.

Please provide a solution. Thanking you very much in advance. I asked my seniors also.

Comment: "Please provide solution"? We will give you help, provided you show us what you have done and explain where you are stuck, but we will not do your work for you.

Comment: I inserted in Survey Table basing on input SID(source),i inserted in Question Table also basing on the new SID , but i want to insert in Answer table for every New QID this is i am facing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO SurveyTable ...
  SELECT ...
  FROM SurveyTable
  WHERE ...
```

Then capture the new row ID and do similar with the other two tables.

Comment: Here SID, QID, AID are PKs in their tables. Pls send example

Comment: I've seen first-hand that not everyone is cut out to be a programmer.

Comment: sorry Order should be like this. New SID -> New QID -> AID. These inter dependent and All should done at one time in SP.